# Sending text commands to another program in C

Tags: c, command

What should I learn if I want to create a **C program** in Windows OS that can send a keyboard command to another program (notepad.exe, lets say)?

Comment: I cant understand the downvotes. Can someone explain?

Comment: Some people (not me) downvoted, because your question is too broad (and you did not mention your OS and other important details) and does not show any code.

Comment: That's because, in the beginning, I didn't know it was an OS specific question, but I can edit it. And about no code, it's because I'm asking for guidance to begin searching in this topic. How could it include some code?

Comment: You should indeed edit your question to improve and to show the code that you have tried

Answer (score 0):

The [C11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_(C_standard_revision)) standard (it is in a document: read [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)) does not know about keyboards or other running programs (except by being able to run them thru some *unspecified* [command processor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_command-line_interpreters) with [`system` function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/system) from `<stdlib.h>`).

<sup>(in pure standard C11, there is no *other* program running with yours : the C standard does not mention [processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing)) which is an OS specific notion)</sup>

Otherwise, you need some [operating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system) specific library (or function, or [system call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call)) able to do [inter-process communication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication). For Linux, read [*Advanced Linux Programming*](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) first. You may need to understand more about the [display server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Display_server) implementing your [window system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windowing_system).

I recommend spending days in reading [*Operating Systems : Three Easy Pieces*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/) to get a good overview about OSes.

You mention some `notepad.exe` so your operating system is probably some Windows. I never used Windows, but found with Google this chapter about [Interprocess Communication on Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365574(v=vs.85).aspx).

You could consider using some cross-platform library like [libsdl](http://libsdl.org/) or [GTK](http://gtk.org/) (or [Qt](http://qt.io/), if you accept coding in C++).

Answer (score -1):

When you run a program ,it will be a process in memory.So,when you have two processes running you can send signals to those processes using the function sigaction or signal.Use the header function 'signal.h' to do so.So,when you want to send a keyboard command,make use of appropriate signal.

Comment: Your answer mention signals, which are mostly POSIX things. The OP mentions `notepad.exe` so probably use a Windows system

Comment: But with the help of wine,we can do this

Comment: I'm not sure that Wine is able to transform Unix signals to their Windows counterparts.

Comment: Every process has a PID,so get the pid and send signals.